# delete entry in DB without reference

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

We have the below requirement:

Currently, we get the data from source (another server, another team, another DB) into a temp DB (via batch jobs) and after we get data into our temp DB, we process the data, transform and update our primary DB with the difference (i.e. the records that changed or the newly added records).

Source->tempDB (daily recreated)->delta->primaryDB

Requirement:
- To delete the data in primary DB once its deleted in source.
Ex: suppose a record with ID=1 is created in source, it comes to temp DB and eventually makes it to primary DB. When this record is deleted in source, it should get deleted in primary DB also.

Challenge:
How do we delete from primary DB when there is nothing to refer to in temp DB (since the record is already deleted in source, nothing comes in tempDB).

Naive approach:
- We can clean up primary DB, before every transform and load afresh. However, it takes a significant amount of time to clean up and populate primary DB everytime.

Comment: Are there any unique fields in those tables that you are deleting from?

Comment: yes, the table has a primary key.

Comment: Why have you tagged MySQL *and* SQL Server?

Comment: Is it viable to delete from your table all ids that do not exist in tempDB?

Comment: Since it's on another server, i'd log the deletions in a table and send it over with a flag.

Comment: @Damir, yes thats the requirement, to delete from table all ids that do not exist in tempDB

Comment: @learner and the issue with that being? can you use "delete from ... where not exists", for example?

Comment: From your primary approach, I will suggest, you push the day2 records from temp to primary. Now primary db `left join` temp db will give you null for records present in primary but not in temp. So flag them/delete them from primary. Makes sense ?

Comment: What are you expecting as an answer here? We can't help with code because we don't even know which DBMS you are using. And you haven't provided any details about the tables involved. About all anybody can offer is some very broad concepts about how you might accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You could create triggers on each table that fills a history table with deleted entries. Synch that over to your tempDB and use it to delete stuff i your primary DB.

You either want one "delete-history-table" per table or a combined history table that also includes the tablename which triggered the deletion.

You might want to look into SQL Compare or other tools for synching tables.

If you have access to tempDB and primeDB (same server or linked servers) at the same time you could also try a

```
delete * 
from primeBD.Tablename 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from tempDB.Tablename where id = primeDB.Tablename.Id
)
```

which will perform awfully - ask your db designers.

Comment: Thanks. Though as you noted, this option is slow.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenorio if TEMPDB & Primary DB have no direct reference then can use track event notification on database level .

Here is the link i got for same :

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2121/event-notifications-in-sql-server-for-tracking-changes/